# How to run a volumetric subdivision in cgal?

Tags: python, cgal

I have a volumetric mesh and want to make the mesh dense. I also want to keep the original nodes in the new mesh, so am wondering if in cgal, there is a simple way to do it? An example will be to add the geometric center of each tetrahedron as a new nodal point to the mesh, and to spit each tetrahedron into 4 small ones. Is there an implementation on this? Python interface is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you should be able to do that by using the [Tetrahedral remeshing package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Tetrahedral_remeshing/index.html).

Comment: Is there an interface in python to do that? Thanks.

Comment: There is not yet.